# Codeigniter 4 error call to a member function paginate() on array

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-4

I want to add Pagination to the user list, but an error occurred during Implementation.
I use Codeigniter 4 and join using Query Builder,

But when I checked an error appeared:

```
error call to a member function paginate () on array
```

Here's the User Controller in my script :

User Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->builder->select('users.id as user_id, username, email, name');
    $this->builder->join('auth_groups_users', 'auth_groups_users.user_id = users.id');
    $this->builder->join('auth_groups', 'auth_groups.id = auth_groups_users.group_id');
    $query = $this->builder->get();

    $users = $query->getResult();

    $data = [
        'title' => 'User List',
        'users' => $users->paginate(3, 'users')
    ];
    return view('user/index', $data);
}
```

Comment: as stated in the error, when you're calling `$users->paginate()` the `$users` variable is still an array as it's the return form `$query-getResult()` you'll need to turn it into whatever class is needed to paginate. Not that familiar with CodeIgniter, but this is as standard PHP error.

Comment: Solved, I made a class on the model, the method is similar to version 3 but the syntax is a little different, thanks for the discussion

Answer (score 0):

$query = $this->builder->get();

$users = $query->getResult();

replace it with $users = $this->paginate(3, 'users');

$data = [ 'title' => 'User List', 'users' => $users ];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).